# Converting Oracle code to TSQL

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I am trying to convert code that is Oracle (PLSQL) to work with  a SQL Server 2012 database. I am converting the Oracle NVL 2 function. I get error in SQL states that isNULL requires 2 arguments.

The Oracle I am trying to convert is:

```
CASE WHEN LTrim(Rtrim(appointtype1)) in ('PRO','NOA') 
      THEN Nvl2(d.phonearea,To_Char(d.phonearea)||'/','')||' '||SubStr(To_Char(d.phonenbr ),1,3)||'-'||SubStr(d.phonenbr,-4)
```

I have the modified for SQL as follows:

```
CASE WHEN LTrim(Rtrim(appointtype1)) in ('PRO','NOA') 
       THEN ISNULL((d.phonearea,CAST(d.phonearea AS char)+'/','')+' '+SubString(CAST(d.phonenbr AS char),1,3)+'-'+SubString(d.phonenbr,-4))
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Oracle's `NVL2(expr1, expr2, expr3` translates to Standard SQL's `CASE WHEN expr1 IS NOT NULL THEN expr2 ELSE expr3 END`

```
CASE WHEN LTrim(Rtrim(appointtype1)) in ('PRO','NOA') 
      THEN CASE WHEN d.phonearea IS NOT NULL
                THEN To_Char(d.phonearea)||'/' 
                ELSE ''
           END ||' '||SubStr(To_Char(d.phonenbr ),1,3)||'-'||SubStr(d.phonenbr,-4)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I *think* this is what you want . . . or at least close:

```
(CASE WHEN LTrim(Rtrim(appointtype1)) IN ('PRO', 'NOA')
      THEN COALESCE(d.phonearea + '/', '') + STUFF(d.phonenbr, 3, 0, '-') 
 END)
```

Notes:

- This assumes that `phonearea` and `phonenbr` are strings, not numbers (storing such values as strings is good practice anyway).
- If they are numbers, then use `CAST()` or `CONVERT()`.  But, remember to include a length for the `VARCHAR()`.  SQL Server has defaults for the length of `VARCHAR()` and you don't want to depend on the default length.
- The `STUFF()` function can be used to insert a hyphen after the 3rd character in the phone number.  I think this is your intended logic.
- You may need to pay attention to casing.  SQL Server (by default) is not case sensitive for most string operations, but Oracle is.